# Can you copy paste tex code from the question without going the "view source" route?

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

I have searched for this but did not find anything relevant.

I was wondering if I can just copy latex code from the OPs question while typing my answer without looking at the html source code in my browser. The latter is often very cumbersome since I have to manually search for the appropriate tex code within a heap of html code.

The reason this would be useful is to cut down time just typing up long equations and such which the OP has already typed and in case, there is a particular element of the tex code that the answerer is not familiar with quickly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right-click on any MathJax rendered object, select "Show Source", then copy the TeX code from the pane.

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What you have to do is the following.

The question URL would be something like

http:// math.stackexchange.com/questions/xxxxx/blahblahblah

Now edit it to make it into

http:// math.stackexchange.com/posts/xxxxx/revisions

with the same question number.

Now choose the edit version you want, and click on "view source".

For example, try it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/11908/revisions

Comment: Never mind my earlier comment. Everything works. Now if only there was a direct way to modify the URL :)

Comment: @Tim: You should probably accept one of the other answers since they give much easier methods. Otherwise readers might miss out on the easier technique.

Comment: This is the best answer. As of today, the other techniques do not work as well as this one does.