# Ability to View Answers in LaTeX

Tags: discussion, mathjax, new-users

Is there an option or can one be implemented so that new users like myself can view the "source code" of others answers.  Obviously there are many tutorials in which we can find the correct commands, but I feel that typesetting math is somewhat of an art form.

If this were the case, maybe some of the moderators wouldn't have to constantly remind new users about proper formatting.  Maybe my idea is awful or I am just being lazy, but I would love to be able to view the LaTeX input of some beautiful looking answers.

Comment: Hit edit button.

Comment: Related: [Can you copy paste tex code from the question without going the “view source” route?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1217) and [Viewing markup of question/answer/comment, of one for which is editing is not allowed.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28616).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes there is! Just right click on the equation you want to view, click "Show Math As" and then click "Tex Commands"

Comment: I have a mac, without a mouse and the ability to right click.  I feel dumb now!

Comment: Here is also a picture: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18889/simple-alignment-to-the-left/18890#18890

Comment: @mathamphetamines: Holding down the Ctrl key and clicking as normal can be used to simulate a right-click on a Mac.

Comment: Or tapping with two fingers if you have a tap to click feature enabled.

Answer (score 7):

The quickest way to see the source for an entire question (or answer) is to start editing it! When your curiosity is satisfied, just click "cancel" instead of "Save Edits".